# spring cloud stream - Can a MicroService a source and a sink at the same time

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

I would have one just simple question - Is it possible that a MicroService (Spring Boot application) is a Source and a Sink at the same time - so is it possible that in a Microservice one class is annotated with

```
@InboundChannelAdapter
```

and another class of the microService is annotated with

```
@StreamListener
```

Comment: If a single micro service needs to act both as a `Source` and `Sink`, another alternative is to make it a `Processor`. Processors receive data from an input destination and sends them to an output destination.

Comment: Which Prcessor du you mean: Spring post processor? Thanks

Comment: No. Use `@EnableBinding(Processor.class)` then you get access to an `@Input` and `@Output`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You just should properly configure binding for them.

You even can use different binders: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#multiple-systems!

Consider this `source` and `sink` capabilities of your Microservice as just *ports* for the application. So, you may have several of them and each may perform independent logic.

Only the problem that you can't use this custom Spring Cloud Stream application in the Spring Cloud Data Flow. There is necessary to follow particular naming and structure convention.